# Individual binwidths in faceted histogram on ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I do a series of histograms with `facet_grid` and I want every histogram in the grid to have the same number of classes, in the example below e.g. 6 classes. The problem in this example below is that `binwidth = diff(range(x$data))/6)` defines the classes according to the overall range of a, b and c, i.e. defines one binwidth for all three facets.

How do I define binwidth individually for the facets a, b and c?

```
require("ggplot2")

a <- c(1.21,1.57,1.21,0.29,0.36,0.29,0.93,0.26,0.28,0.48,
       0.12,0.38,0.83,0.82,0.41,0.69,0.25,0.98,0.52,0.11)
b <- c(0.42,0.65,0.17,0.38,0.44,0.01,0.01,0.03,0.15,0.01)
c <- c(1.09,3.55,1.07,4.55,0.55,0.11,0.72,0.66,1.22,3.04,
       2.01,0.64,0.47,1.33,3.44)

x <- data.frame(data = c(a,b,c), variable = c(rep("a",20),rep("b",10),rep("c",15)),area="random")

qplot(data, data = x, geom = "histogram", binwidth = diff(range(x$data))/6) +
  facet_grid(area~variable, scales = "free")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not optimal but you can do the histogram in different layers:

```
ggplot(x, aes(x=data)) +
   geom_histogram(data=subset(x, variable=="a"), binwidth=.1) +
   geom_histogram(data=subset(x, variable=="b"), binwidth=.2) +
   geom_histogram(data=subset(x, variable=="c"), binwidth=.5) +
   facet_grid(area~variable, scales="free")
```

Comment: This "Brute Force" method might be not optimal, but works very well. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

One way is to pre-summarize your data in the way you want it, then to create the plot.

In your case, you need to bin your variables using the function `cut()`.  The package `dplyr` is convenient for this, because it allows you to specify a mutate function for each group of your data:

```
library(dplyr)

zz <- x %>%
  group_by(variable) %>%
  mutate(
    bins = cut(data, breaks=6)
  )

qplot(bins, data = zz, geom = "histogram", fill=I("blue")) +
  facet_grid(area~variable, scales = "free") +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle=90))
```

[image]

Comment: While this method principially works well, it does only produce a row of graphs with the same x-axis ranges. Because i have different ranges, i went with the "brute force" method of wije. Still, thank you for your input!