# Different Binwidth for Each Plot of a Facet

Tags: r, ggplot2

Trying to understand assigning unique `binwidth` for each factor level in `geom_histogram`.
So far failed though.

Here is the reproducible data

```
a <- rnorm(10,7,0.1)
b <- rnorm(10,13,5)
df <- data.frame(data = c(a,b),group=c(rep("a",10),rep("b",10)))
kk <- df%>%
  group_by(group)%>%
  mutate(bin=density(data)$bw)

binns <- round(unique(kk$bin),digits = 2)  # to get each binwidth for each group

ggplot()+
  geom_histogram(data=kk,aes(x=data, fill=group),binwidth=binss)+
  facet_wrap(~group,scales=c("free_y"))

Error in seq.default(round_any(range[1], size, floor),    round_any(range[2],  : 
  'from' must be of length 1
Error in seq.default(round_any(range[1], size, floor), round_any(range[2],  : 
  'from' must be of length 1
Error in exists(name, envir = env, mode = mode) : 
  argument "env" is missing, with no default
```

Then I tried

```
ggplot()+
  geom_histogram(data=kk,aes(x=data, fill=group),binwidth=c(binns[1],binns[2]))+
  facet_wrap(~group,scales=c("free_y"))
```

The same error happened. I couldn't understand why it is giving the same error.

Comment: you could plot the two histograms in different [layers](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24571547/4964651)

Comment: @mtoto What if I have 30 levels in df ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could iterate on bins to create layers

```
library(dplyr)
a <- rnorm(10,7,0.1)
b <- rnorm(10,13,5)
df <- data.frame(data = c(a,b),group=c(rep("a",10),rep("b",10)))
kk <- df %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  mutate(bin=round(density(data)$bw, 2))
binns <- unique(kk$bin)
```

Attach `ggplot2`

```
library(ggplot2)
```

Create in a list one histogram layer per bin value with data only for this bin. If you have 30 level, you'll have a list of 30 histogram layers

```
lp_hist <- plyr::llply(binns, function(b) {
  geom_histogram(data = kk %>% 
                   filter(bin == b), 
                 aes(x = data, fill=group), 
                 binwidth = b)
  })
```

Combine those layers, adding them all to `ggplot()` object

```
p_hist <- Reduce("+", lp_hist, init = ggplot())
```

Facet and scale as you want

```
p_hist + facet_grid(. ~ group, scales = "free_y")
```

you'll obtain the graph you want that is to say a different binwidth by facet.

[image: hist.plot]

Watch out because 30 levels will give 30 facets... it is a lot.

*Nota: Using `dplyr 0.4.3`, `ggplot2 2.1.0` and `plyr 1.8.3` on `R 3.2.3`*

Comment: thanks for the answer. However I am getting error when I do `p_hist`  its says that `Error in exists(name, envir = env, mode = mode) : 
  argument "env" is missing, with no default` I am not sure its because of conflict in between  `plyr` and `dplyr` packages?

Comment: I run it again and it works for me. I use `dplyr 0.4.3`, `ggplot2  2.1.0` and `plyr 1.8.3` on `R 3.2.3`.
 Do you copy paste the code? Can you try it agin? 
It should work.

Comment: I updated all the packages as you have. I copy paste your code. Now I understand the problem. Thank you very much. Its solved. All the best!

Comment: A potential problem here,  in `kk %>% 
                   filter(bin == b)`. If we have same `b` for different groups?