# ggplot facet_wrap histogram using binwidth as a column value

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a data.frame that I want to use facet_wrap on. My data looks like so:

```
head(anomalize_long_facet_tbl, 18)
# A time tibble: 18 x 4
# Index:  arrival
# Groups: time_segment [9]
   arrival             value time_segment                    bw_value
   <dttm>              <int> <chr>                              <dbl>
 1 2019-01-01 00:00:00   300 arr_to_dta_minutes                 66.4 
 2 2019-01-01 00:00:00    83 dta_to_adm_ord_entry_minutes        9.53
 3 2019-01-01 00:00:00     2 adm_ord_to_adm_confirm_minutes      7.46
 4 2019-01-01 00:00:00     2 adm_confirm_to_tack_minutes         2.39
 5 2019-01-01 00:00:00    17 track_to_adm_bed_minutes            3.42
 6 2019-01-01 00:00:00   346 adm_bed_to_leave_ed_minutes        41.6 
 7 2019-01-01 00:00:00    12 first_non_er_bed_minutes          126.  
 8 2019-01-01 00:00:00   750 arrival_to_leave_ed_minutes       118.  
 9 2019-01-01 00:00:00   762 arr_to_first_non_er_bed_minutes   126.  
10 2019-01-01 00:00:00   156 arr_to_dta_minutes                 66.4 
11 2019-01-01 00:00:00    53 dta_to_adm_ord_entry_minutes        9.53
12 2019-01-01 00:00:00     5 adm_ord_to_adm_confirm_minutes      7.46
13 2019-01-01 00:00:00     0 adm_confirm_to_tack_minutes         2.39
14 2019-01-01 00:00:00     4 track_to_adm_bed_minutes            3.42
15 2019-01-01 00:00:00   239 adm_bed_to_leave_ed_minutes        41.6 
16 2019-01-01 00:00:00     8 first_non_er_bed_minutes          126.  
17 2019-01-01 00:00:00   457 arrival_to_leave_ed_minutes       118.  
18 2019-01-01 00:00:00   465 arr_to_first_non_er_bed_minutes   126.
```

I want to create a 3x3 facet_wrap geom_histogram plot using the data. I have written the following:

```
anomalize_long_facet_tbl %>%
  ggplot(
    mapping = aes(
      x = value
      , fill = time_segment
      , group = time_segment
    )
  ) +
  facet_wrap(~ time_segment) +
  geom_histogram(binwidth = anomalize_long_facet_tbl$bw_value) +
  theme_tq()
```

I get the following error:

```
Warning messages:
1: Computation failed in `stat_bin()`:
length(width) == 1 is not TRUE
```

So it is obvious either my syntax is wrong or my understanding is. Can this sort of thing be accomplished via ggplot? I have managed to do it via regular hist() with a loop:

```
par(mfrow = c(3,3))
for(i in 1:length(cols_to_anomalize)){
  c <- cols_to_anomalize[i]
  title <- str_c("Hist for: ", c %>% str_to_title())
  filt_col <- str_c("anomaly_", c)
  df_tmp <- df_tbl %>%
    filter(!!sym(filt_col) == "No") %>%
    select(contains(c), -contains("anomaly_")) %>%
    pull() %>%
    enframe()
  bw <- optBin(df_tmp$value)
  bw <- bw %>%
    enframe() %>%
    mutate(lag_1 = lag(value, n = 1)) %>%
    mutate(lag_1 = case_when(
      is.na(lag_1) ~ value
      , TRUE ~ lag_1
    )) %>%
    mutate(lag_1_delta = value - lag_1) %>%
    select(lag_1_delta) %>%
    tail(1) %>%
    pull()

  hist(df_tmp$value, main = title, breaks = bw)
}
par(mfrow = c(1,1))
```

Here is a plot using the base hist() function:
[image]

Comment: Binwidth should be a single number, because all the bins will have the same width. Maybe you're trying to set breaks instead...?

Comment: no it's definitely binwidth

Comment: I could understand wanting a different binwidth in each facet... but wanting a different binwidth for each bar doesn't sound like a histogram anymore. Perhaps if you posted an image of your successful base plotting that would help clarify the goal?

Comment: I do want a different binwidth for each facet.

Comment: Ah, the way your sample data is arranged it's hard to see there are duplicates in the binwidth - at a glance I thought they were all unique.

Comment: Right, but right now you're passing in a whole vector of binwidths, i.e. it's getting c(66.4, 9.53, 7.46,...) as the binwidth. If you want to do different binwidths per facet, you might have to instead split the data and create multiple plots, then stick them together as though they were facets.

Comment: added a plot using base hist() function

Comment: gridExtra::grid.arrange() here I come I guess

Comment: Or patchwork or cowplot! Either of those should make it pretty painless

Comment: I think you'd do better to create an example data set with 2 facets. The sample data you've shared doesn't have enough values in any single facet to be a useful example.

Comment: Not an easy way, per se, but not too bad: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35749885/903061 .

Comment: With out edits, I think it's appropriate to close this as a dupe. Even if a better example is provided here, it's probably still a good dupe. If you're unsatisfied with the answer at the dupe, the best way to draw attention to it is probably to offer a bounty for a new answer.

Comment: actually I agree with you that this is a good dupe. I ended up using that as my answer. Thanks for sharing it.